# Java - Can I multiply referenced values?

Tags: java, object, reference, pass-by-reference

If I have a class as follows, just to store a value:

```
public class RefTest{
    private int value;

    public void setValue(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }

   public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

and want RefTest b to always be double RefTest a, how would I go about it? Currently I have the values equal:

```
RefTest a = new RefTest();
a.setValue(5);
RefTest b = new RefTest();
b = a;
System.out.println("RefTest a: "+a.getValue());
System.out.println("RefTest b: "+b.getValue());
a.setValue(10);
System.out.println("RefTest a: "+a.getValue());
System.out.println("RefTest b: "+b.getValue());
```

But I'm not sure how to go about setting b to 2*a, as "b=2*a" returns an error(as expected), and b.setValue(2*a.getValue()) doesn't update when a.setValue() changes.

Comment: You can't do this with your current implementation of `RefTest`.  You would have to create separate subclasses.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you do `b.setValue(1)`? Does `a` get updated too? If so, what value should it be updated to? (Don't say 0, because clearly 1 ≠ 2 * 0)

Comment: @Sweeper a would get updated to .5, so I suppose I would change int to double.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking to accomplish can't be done the way you've implemented `RefTest`

The fact you want a and b to behave differently means they can't really be the same `RefTest` object.

While the requirement is a bit odd, from a reference perspective you need to actually store a reference to the object (a in this case) instead of the int value which is not a reference (that value is computed and set at the time you call setValue).  You'll still need to do other work to actually ensure your getValue is always two times whatever value a is.

You'll need to actually define two separate objects, where the behaviour of 'b' would be the variable (which can be a reference to another object) if it has an intValue be two times that value

If you're new to Java please look into differences between int and an object reference in instance variables, and also patterns like composition (which could help you in this scenario)

Comment: How would you go about this? I see what you mean, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: See the reply by Dave Costa below, it's a good example

Answer (score 1):

Taking your definition of `RefTest` as given, define another class like:

```
public class RefTestMultiple{
   private RefTest source;
   private int multiplier;

   RefTestMultiple(RefTest source, int multiplier) {
      this.source = source;
      this.multiplier = multiplier;
   }    

   public int getValue() {
        return multiplier * source.getValue();
   }
```

You can use it like this:

```
RefTest a = new RefTest();
RefTestMultiple b = new RefTestMultiple(a,2);
a.setValue(5);
System.out.println(b.getValue());
```

Comment: And then just do one of each of these for any other arithemtic I'd want to do?

Comment: @LukeO'Meara You certainly could.  I don't understand your overall goal so I don't know if this is the best way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think b = a is doing what you think it is doing. What you want instead is:

```
b.setValue(a.getValue());
```

And for b = 2a what you want is:

```
b.setValue(2 * a.getValue());
```

Indeed the value of b will not update when the value of a changes. This is not math, these are procedural expressions.

Comment: I'm specifically looking for a way to do this where b.value does update when a.value does. Is that not doable in Java?

Comment: Not with a mathematical expression like b = 2a. In java that is a simple assignment that occurs once with the value of a. Java doesn't automatically update the values of things for you.

The only way to do the auto updating you want would be to have some class that wraps a and have a method get2A() that calculates 2a every time it is called.